# PHP Warning: require and PHP Fatal error: require()

Tags: laravel

I run this :

```
php artisan serve
```

but I got this error:

```
PHP Warning:  require(/opt/lampp/htdocs/phonebook/vendor/composer/../ralouphie/getallheaders/src/getallheaders.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs/phonebook/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/opt/lampp/htdocs/phonebook/vendor/composer/../ralouphie/getallheaders/src/getallheaders.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /opt/lampp/htdocs/phonebook/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing your dependencies. Please run

```
composer install
```

in the root directory to install dependencies

Comment: did you run composer install?

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 run:

`composer install`

Step 2:

```
php artisan key:generate
```

it should work

Comment: I got this Error : PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/blog/artisan:36
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /opt/lampp/htdocs/blog/artisan on line 36